Do me'ah rabbonim become a King?
I have read that me'ah(100) rabbonim together have special capacities than otherwise. Do me'ah rabbonim become a King or are they still not a king.

In what respect?

The "100 rabbis" trick is an escape valve for the relatively late ban against polygamy. It's used if the first wife is unable or unwilling to receive a Gett, and a Gett is left in escrow. That's about it.

Only in checkers and chess do pawns become kings. :-)

@DannySchoemann Also in the game of life.

Why would you think that 100 rabbonim “become a King”? The use of “heter meah rabbonim” is quite specific: to enable the remarriage of a man whose wife refuses to accept a get.
So, no me'ah rabbonim do not become a king.

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.
